# Apache Cordova Problem: $ cordova build can't complete. How to solve error with build.gradle?

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I've been trying to install and run my first app via Apache Cordova, I've seen multiple tutorials on how to install it properly, I've done every single step as I should've but I still run into the same problem every single time. I've installed everything properly (when I check versions of node, cordova, java, adb and gradle, it all shows exactly as it should. Now when I type **cordova build** I get the next error every time:

First: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\myapp\platforms\android\cdv-gradle-name.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile script 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\myapp\platforms\android\cdv-gradle-name.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61

Second:   1 error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 948ms
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\User\Desktop\myapp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\User\Desktop\myapp\platforms\android\build.gradle

I've searched for an answer for quite a while, tried all of the solutions but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: What are you JDK & Gradle versions ?

Comment: JDK-17.0.1 and Gradle 7.3.3